# Binary to decimal...wrong output

Tags: c, pointers, binary, output, decimal

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{          
    char *bin=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    int i=0,p=0,dec=0,g;

    printf("\nenter the binary number\n");
    gets(bin);
    i=strlen(bin)-1;
    while(*(bin+p)!=NULL){

        if(*(bin+p)=='1'){
            g=pow(2,(i-p));
            dec=dec+g;
        }
        p++;
    }
    printf("\n%d",dec);

return 0;
}
```

Above program should convert ANY bits binary number to decimal.

Sample input:

```
10011
```

Expected output:

```
19
```

Actual output:

```
1
```

Comment: `gets` was removed from the C language 4 years ago, was made depricated 16 years ago  and it was recognized as bad practice maybe 30 years ago.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz please check again I have edited some part...

Comment: @Lundin But it still works on my compiler...I have checked

Comment: @AkshayMilmile sigh, _indent_ your code

Comment: @Lundin Also please tell me how to use fgets...it says too few arguments... Also it requires file name as last arguments...which I am not getting what do...

Comment: @AkshayMilmile No, it does not require a file name, it requires a stream such as `stdin`. [LMRTFMFY](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: turn on compiler warnings. I got several warnings and a compiler error when compiling your code.

That said, there is an error in the use of the pow function. You can fix it by setting `i` to a proper value:

```
gets(bin);
i = strlen(bin) - 1;
```

This will make the code work provided the input is correct (only  ones and zeroes, no longer than the number of bits in an `int`).

You should also replace `gets` with `fgets`:

```
fgets(bin, 100, stdin);
```

Note that if the string fits, `fget`s will also put the newline character in the string, so you need to remove that.

After fixing the warnings I got when compiling with `gcc -Wall`, the code looked like this (I didn't bother changing `gets` to `fgets`):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *bin=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
  int i=0,p=0,dec=0,g;

  printf("\nenter the binary number\n");
  gets(bin);
  i = strlen(bin) - 1;

  while(*(bin+p)!='\0'){
    if(*(bin+p)=='1'){
      g=pow(2,(i-p));
      dec=dec+g;
    }
    p++;
  }
  printf("\n%d",dec);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the already pointed out issue of `gets` there is some `}` mismatch in your code. But the logic is missing the value of `i`. In your code you are subtracting `p` from `i` which is always 0. Try to set the value of `i` before the loop, like this -
`i = strlen(bin) - 1;`

Also, add some error checking in your code too.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this solves your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{          
char *bin = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
int i=0, p =0,dec=0,g;

printf("\nenter the binary number\n");
gets(bin);
i = strlen(bin);
i = i - 1;
while(*(bin+p)!='\0'){

    if((*(bin+p))=='1'){
        g=pow(2,(i-p));
        dec=dec+g;
    }
    p++;
}
printf("\n%d",dec);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Folks have already pointed out various issue. Apart from that, you might want to change you program as follows. Also keep in mind, just for demonstration, I' am setting value of `bin` within the program. You still want to take user input for `bin`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{

char *bin=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
int i=0,p=0,dec=0,g;

printf("\nenter the binary number\n");
//gets(bin);
bin = "1011";
int len = strlen(bin);
i = len;

while(i > 0)
{
    if(*(bin+p)=='1')
    {
        g=pow(2,(len-p-1));
        dec=dec+g;
    }
    p++;
    i--;
}
printf("\n%d",dec);

return 0;
}
```